# Evaluating JavaScript return functions provided by users

Tags: javascript, eval

What is the best way to evaluate a String function that a user provides?

For example, a user may enter this into the input box:

`"return document.title"` (stored in `var fn`)

And I will evaluate that on the current page:

`var result = eval("(function(){"+fn+"})()");`

Is there a safer method to do this? Are there libraries that can help scrub malicious code?

Comment: What's the context? Why are users providing input like this?

Comment: Users would choose from pages on my site (page1.html, page2.html), and provide a function to return some data (like `document.title` or `window.someVariable`). So both the URL and the return function are user-entered.

Comment: You can use the `Function` constructor instead of `eval` so that they can't  access your local variables, but otherwise it's really not unsafe if you're just running the code in the user's own browser. The only one they could harm would be themselves.

Comment: If the code is always only executed on the page itself, never sent to the server and distributed to other users, then using `eval` doesn't really have any security issues. You might want to use the `Function` constructor function instead, or global `eval`, to not leak potentially private closures variables. *edit:* What squint said :P

Comment: Thanks! And what if I am executing this on other web pages where they would want scope access?